# This iterator instead of returning N elements returns always 4. What's going on?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, moving-average

```
    result_list = [result, first_result_value]
    for i in data_list[:2]:
        i = ((i - result_list[-1]) * multiplier + result_list[-1])   
        result_list.append(float(i))
return result_list
```

No matter how long is `data_list` it always gives a `result_list` with 4 numbers. I also tried this for the loop but gives the same:

```
for i in data_list[:2]:
    zz = ((i - result_list[-1]) * multiplier + result_list[-1])   
    result_list.append(float(zz))
return result_list
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data_list[:2] will yield the first 2 elements of an array.

data_list[2:] will skip the first 2 elements of an array and yield the remaining elements.

Note the position of the ':' in the array slice.

Comment: Spot on, you totally got what I tried but failed to do: skipping the first two elements, thank you so much this is my first time coding and I was desperate

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what these functions are trying to do, it would be nice if you could give an explenation. To answer your question regarding the length of the ema_list we can check were you are actually changing it.

Here you initialize the ema_list with **two** values:

```
ema_list = [sma, first_ema_value]
```

After that, you iterate **two** steps through your loop

```
for i in data_list[:2]:
```

So to answer your question: the reason that the resulting ema_list is of length 4 is that you initialize it with two values and then append 2 values more. If you would like to iterate through all the values in data_list change

```
for i in data_list[:2]:
```

into

```
for i in data_list:
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, slicing was the problem, I was trying to skip as Kristian noticed